# How can I convert an orthographic camera to a perspective camera?

Tags: camera, perspective

How can calculate perspective camera parameters from orthographic camera parameters (left, right, top, bottom, near, far)?

Specifically I don't know how calculate the FOV for a perspective camera from orthographic camera.

Comment: You should create a question (or edit this one) that describes the feature that you need instead of asking about solution implementation. ([XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)) This way we could give you better answers.

Comment: In theory, if your perspective FOV will be infinitely small, then said perspective matrix will kind of resemble orthographic matrix .. but I'm sure you need something less "extreme".

Comment: I need way to get data for creation perspective camera (fov ,aspect,near,far , matrix) if I have data for creation orthographic camera  (left, right, top, bottom, near, far, matrix).

Comment: What are these matrices? The way to project stuff on screen is by using lots of matrices, so just saying 'matrix' adds some confusion...

Comment: Matrix determine position of camera and direction of camera view.

Comment: The trick is that there are **many** perspective cameras that could be considered "similar" to a given orthographic one (but never the same), & we don't know **which one** you want. The orientation & aspect ratio are the only unambiguous properties they share — everything else we need to make some judgement calls about what parts of the scene view we want to preserve after our camera change (eg. We could pick a planar slice through the scene at a particular depth where we want the projections of objects to remain invariant) — you need to give us more context or info on what calls to make here.

Answer (score 5):

You can't.

The two matrices are constructed in completely different ways.

There are tons of ways to find more information on that by googling.

You can't get the field of view from the orthographic camera because there is no such thing.

Comment: Isn't there a hackish way to get the fov? Like `0.5f * (right - left) / (far - near)` which would give us `0.5f * tan(fov)` (which we can use to make perspective matrix given a ratio)? Though the view will be completely different from the ortho one ofc..

Comment: One could hackishly try to approximate the volume rendered; not sure about how I'd go about it exaclty, but you're right, the views would look different.